# TLP can't find my battery

Tags: power-management, battery, tlp

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on Surface 3. For some reason TLP can't see my laptop battery...

```
$ sudo tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------
+++ Battery Status
No batteries detected.*
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please add the output of `tlp-stat -s --psup` **running on battery** to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Unsupported hardware, the battery is missing a driver for Linux and you can expect Microsoft to not supply one

[wiki.gnome.org](https://wiki.gnome.org/BastienNocera/Surface%203) has a run down on what does and does not work and the [Bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106231) it refers to in regards to the battery. There are some patches in the bug report but nothing made it into the kernel yet.

On the [lkml mailing list](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/8/31/538) is a run down on the work Bastien Nocera did (same person who made the wiki.gnome.org link).

edit:

Maybe there is a way: there is a [generic patch](https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface) that includes Debian and Ubuntu. That will be your best bet.

Comment: gratz! gotta love open source :D Please upvote and/or accept if you feel it is acceptable That'll remove it from the open answers queue